# How to output html from a filter in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have defined a filter as follows

```
@angular.module('extcomFilters',[]).filter('status_icon',()->
  (input) ->
    if input <=0
      "<i class='icon-thumbs-down'></i>"
    else
      "<i class='icon-thumbs-up'></i>"
)
```

so depending on the status, I can get one icon or the other one. I'm using it inside a span tag using the ng-bind-html-unsafe directive:

```
 <span data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{status | status_icon}}"></span>
```

Instead of having the icon displayed inside the span element, I'm getting this:

```
<span data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="&lt;i class='icon-thumbs-up'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;"></span>
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by injecting $sce service in my filter:

```
filter('status_icon',['$sce', ($sce)->
  (input) ->
    if input == null or input == ''
      return $sce.trustAsHtml("<i class='icon-thumbs-down'></i>")
    else if input >= 0
      return $sce.trustAsHtml("<i class='icon-thumbs-up'></i>")
    else if input < 0
      return "loading..."
])
```

and using ng-bind-html in the span element:

```
 <span data-ng-bind-html="status | status_icon"></span>
```

Comment: Odd, I had a need to do the very same thing today, but it worked without having to inject $sce.  All I did was add <div ng-bind-html="field | myFilterFn"></div> to my view and inject ngSanitize in my module using angular.module('myModule', ['ngSanitize']) and the HTML returned.

Comment: To be honest, I did not try to access $sce.trustAsHtml without injecting it, I just assumed I had to do it. I just removed the injection and got "ReferenceError: $sce is not defined" error.

Comment: What I meant was to remove the $sce injection and then simply return "<i class='icon-thumbs-up'></i>".  It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you include the Sanitize module in your controller?  Without it the attribute will just be interpreted as a non-angular attribute.  It appears in your example that you just need ng-bind-html, so perhaps give that a try.

Comment: I added the ngSanitize module, which was missing, and injected $sanitize in my controller. I got the same output when using ng-bind-html-unsafe. When I use ng-bind-html, at least I get content inside the span tag. I'll have a look at the $sanitize docs. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I solved it injecting $sce service into my filter and using $sce.trustAsHtml